# how to generate dynamic tooltips with data from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a PHP script that retrieves a number of random fields from one column in MYSQL and echos them to a page. What I want to be able to do is hover mouse over any of the echoed results and display a tooltip which shows additional information from my databse- such as info from two relevant fields in two separate columns in MYSQL database

Would I have to include these extra colums in my SQL select statement and some how pass these to javascript to display tooltip or is there a way to do it with PHP alone?

I'm fairly new to PHP and my javascript knowledge is thin. The idea sounds simple but I have a feeling it's going to be very difficult to do.

Anyway, here is my code which has been helped out by mmmshuddup (cheers for that). I realise that I haven't protected against SQL injections yet. But I will! 
Thanks.

```
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name  
$username=""; // Mysql username  
$password=""; // Mysql password  
$db_name="db"; // Database name  
$tbl_name="sentence"; // Table name  

// Connect to server and select databse. 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");  
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 

$sn=$_POST['numberofsentences']; 


$query="SELECT line FROM `sentence` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $sn"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 

$count = 0;  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    // do something with $row. The following echos the results and adds a space after each sentence.  
    echo $row['line'], "&nbsp";  
    if ($count >= 4) {  
        echo '<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';  
        $count = 0;  
    } else {  
        $count++;  
    }  
} 
// Close the database connection 
mysql_close(); 

 ?>
```

Comment: Could you just give us / me an example how it should look in the end? Becuase, the only thing you currently doing is, printing whitespaces and a newline.

Comment: The code echos out four sentences from database and groups them into paragraph. The white spaces are an indent so that it looks like a paragraph when read on screen. So the final result shows  4 sentences in a paragraph, then a line break, then another paragraph containing four sentences (with an indent of 4 white spaces). This is repeated until all results are used. It looks pretty much the same way as if you were reading a book. What I want to do is be able to hover mouse over each sentence and display a tooltip about that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Their is list of built in tooltip plugins, you can use any one just like

1- load first time all information to multiple divs with seprate ids
2- show and hide on based upon time or what so ever you want

here is one example of tooptip that i have used it, found it suited my need [link here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go down the route of using Javascript, you can use the HTML title tag like so:

```
<a href="whatever.php" title="<?php echo $tooltip; ?>">some link</a>
```

That should give you a simple tooltip. For anything fancier though you'll need to use Javascript.

Comment: How does that work? Where would the HTML code go -would it go in my PHP script? Sorry, I don't understand how I can use this to display data from MYSQL?

Comment: The best way to do it is to separate the HTML from the MySQL altogether. Instead of looping through a MySQL result set to produce the HTML, loop through the MySQL result set to create an array. Then, loop through that array later on to create the HTML.